# Query to Select All Non-Essential Temporary Files

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject, wql

I am trying to write a script to delete unneeded temporary files. I am wanting to specifically target .tmp's, though. At least for now. So I am trying to write a WQL query to return a collection with which I can use a FOR EACH statement to delete all of the .tmp's in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp. I've only recently started learning VBScript. But I have experience writing programs in C/C++ (mainly "math-y" programs).

Cscript seems to have no problem with the query itself. But when I try to use the Count method on the resulting collection, cscript returns an error: (17,1) Microsoft VBVScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'colTempFiles.Count'.

I've read up on WQL a little bit, thinking that maybe I'm not getting a collection returned for some reason. But I can't seem to find anything wrong with the query. I'm thinking that maybe I shouldn't be selecting from FileSystemObject. But I've read what I can find about it, and it seems to be the right thing to do (although there really isn't a lot of helpful info on MSDN).

Anyway, here's the script I currently have, without comments. The second line is something I am not currently using, but am going to try to use later, so that I can define a variable as the local computer's username and not have to point to the local Temp folder's path specifically. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
strComputer = "."
strUser="adam"


Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")


Set colTempFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
 ("SELECT * FROM FileSystemObject WHERE Name = '*.tmp' AND "_
 & "NOT Name LIKE 'Prf%' AND Path LIKE 'C:\Users\adam\AppData\Local\Temp\%'")

colTempFiles.Count



For Each objFile in colTempFiles
Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
 'Set objF=objFSO.GetFile("objFile.Path")
 'objF.Delete(True)
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing two different technologies. A `FileSystemObject` is a *COM class* that needs to be instantiated using `CreateObject()` in VBScript. For WQL, you need to use a *WMI class* in your query. Here is [a core list of WMI classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For your purposes, you'll want to use the `CIM_DataFile` class to work with files.

You can use either technology. The `FileSystemObject` is the preferred method if you're working with the local file system. If you need to work with files on a remote machine, use WMI and WQL.

Here's an example using a `FileSystemObject`:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\adam\AppData\Local\Temp")

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If StrComp(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path), "tmp", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        objFile.Delete    ' This is the Delete() method of the FSO's "File" class
    End If
Next
```

And here's an example using WQL:

```
strComputer = "."

' Connect to the WMI service on the specified computer...
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

' Build our WQL query...
strQuery = "select * from CIM_DataFile "
strQuery = strQuery & "where Drive='C:' "
strQuery = strQuery & "and Path='\\Users\\adam\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\' "
strQuery = strQuery & "and Name like '%.tmp'"

' Run the query...
Set colTempFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery)

' Delete each file...
For Each objFile In colTempFiles
    objFile.Delete    ' This is the Delete() method of the WMI "CIM_DataFile" class
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Like I said, I've just started learning VBScript. So I didn't really know the difference between WMI and COM classes. I just threw the script together based on what I've seen. It's working perfectly now.